# Extend keyword in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

What does extend do in protobuf?
For example, in a .proto file I have something like

```
extend ReportConfig {
  optional PerfStandardReportConfig perf_standard_report = 201;
  optional PerfCategoryReportConfig perf_category_report = 202;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `extend` keyword in `Protobuf` is used to define extensions to a message type. Extensions are a way to add new fields to a message type without having to change the original message type definition.

P.S: `extend` is a discouraged feature from `Protobuf` version 3

Comment: @Sh Shiva Reddy does it answer your question?